# Cannot delete a node using REST

Tags: 7, services

I'm using a [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) and [RESTful Web Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws), All is Okay with me except the deleting and updating node, I've activated the node CRUD resource in my service. When hit the URL using DELETE

> MY_SITE/ENDPOINT/node/delete

I got Response as TRUE with status 200 OK. As I've read on the internet that if I want to delete a node, I should hit a URL like this, including nid in the last argument

> MY_SITE/ENDPOINT/node/delete/NID

But I got 404 Not found. So I want to know the error that I've made or what is the correct way to delete node using services and restful.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used restws, but given that it has 'rest' in the name wouldn't it follow standard conventions and use a `DELETE` request straight to `/endpoint/node/{nid}`?

Comment: Clive's comment is correct, send the `DELETE` request to the aforementioned URL path. Also, I wouldn't advise using both `services` and `restws` together, as I'd imagine they'd battle with each other in some way.

Comment: I'm already sending `DELETE` request. So what I should use with `services` instead of  `restws`